# Query values not getting in next.js

Tags: next.js13

```
<Link href={`posts?postId=${data.id}`} as={`posts/${data.slug}`}>
     View Post
</Link>
```

/posts/[postId]/page.tsx

```
'use client'

import ModalWrapper from '@/components/Wrapper/ModalWrapper'
import { useParams, useRouter, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import ProductDetails from './ProductDetails'
import { useMediaQuery } from '@mui/material'

const page = () => {

    const params = useParams()

    console.log('params',params);
    
    const router = useRouter()

    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState<boolean>(true);

    const isSmallScreen = useMediaQuery('(max-width:768px)');

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isSmallScreen) {
            setShowModal(false)
        } else {

            setShowModal(true)
        }
    }, [isSmallScreen]);

    const handleCloseModal = () => {
        setShowModal(false)
        router.back()
    }

    if (!isSmallScreen) {
        return (
            <ModalWrapper showModal={showModal} handleShowModal={handleCloseModal} >
                <ProductDetails />
            </ModalWrapper>
        );
    }

    return (
        <ProductDetails />
    )
}

export default page
```

I am working on next.js app route project.
When i am clicking the view Post button and it's navigating to the post details page. Here i am trying mask the url id to the slug of the post. I need the post id in the deatils page. But in this code not getting the url.

I wan to get the post id in the details page through query and the id of the post no need to show in the url. it's should mask with the slug or post name. and in the post details page i want to fetch the post details with the help of the id.